# clarification on Neo4j's performance good practice

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The docs state:

> Specify the target database on all queries, either with the database_ parameter in Driver.execute_query() or with the database parameter when creating new sessions. If no database is provided, the driver has to send an extra request to the server to figure out what the default database is. The overhead is minimal for a single query, but becomes significant over hundreds of queries.

and gives 2 examples:

```
# Good practice
driver.execute_query("<QUERY>", database_="<DB NAME>")
driver.session(database="<DB NAME>")

# Bad practice
driver.execute_query("<QUERY>")
driver.session()
```

Does that mean that

```
# Good practice
driver.execute_query("<QUERY>", database_="<DB NAME>")
driver.session()
```

and this

```
# Good practice
driver.execute_query("<QUERY>")
driver.session(database="<DB NAME>")
```

are good practices or should I specify the database name in `execute_query()` **and** `session()`?

Comment: [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/python-manual/current/performance/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation could be a bit clearer.

`driver.execute_query` and `driver.session` actually represent 2 *different ways* to execute queries. You would use one call or the other, but not together.

It would have been clearer for the documentation to say something like:

```
# Good practice
driver.execute_query("<QUERY>", database_="<DB NAME>")
  OR
driver.session(database="<DB NAME>")

# Bad practice
driver.execute_query("<QUERY>")
  OR
driver.session()
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback -- that page has now been updated and hopefully any confusion cleared.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you execute a query (with `driver.execute_query` or with any session/transaction API), specifying the target database if you know it in advance, is a good idea.

Why? Because Neo4j introduced the "home database" concept, which allows different users to have default databases.

If you do not not specify what database you target, the driver will first have to communicate with the server to figure out what the home database is for the given user.

Since the home database can be changed at any time, the driver only caches that information once per session.

Therefore, you should specify the target database at the session configuration level every time you use a session API, to avoid that resolution process to kick in.

Since `driver.execute_query` is a facade on session's retryable transaction APIs (the driver manages the session for you in this case), you also need to specify the database there, if you want the managed session to be properly configured.

Note: there are ongoing internal discussions to improve the way drivers handle the "home database resolution" issue, so stay tuned for potential improvements in the next releases!